# Recursive SQL to split CSV to table rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, recursive-query

After working on a different question here on SO, I stumbled across recursive CTEs which would on the surface seem a fairly easy way to solve the "Split a csv to table rows" problem.

I put this example together

```
DECLARE @InputString varchar(255) = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z'

SELECT @InputString = @InputString + ','
;
with MyCTE(x,y)
as 
(
    SELECT 
        x = SUBSTRING(@InputString,0,PATINDEX('%,%',@InputString)),
        y = SUBSTRING(@InputString,PATINDEX('%,%',@InputString)+1,LEN(@InputString))
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            x = SUBSTRING(y,0,PATINDEX('%,%',y)),
            y = SUBSTRING(y,PATINDEX('%,%',y)+1,LEN(y))
        FROM 
            MyCTE 
        WHERE
                SUBSTRING(y,PATINDEX('%,%',y)+1,LEN(y)) <> '' OR 
            SUBSTRING(y,0,PATINDEX('%,%',y)) <> ''
)
SELECT x FROM MyCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000);
GO
```

Is this really a bad idea? What is the overhead in SQL for recursive queries like this, and what are the potential pitfalls for this kind of approach.

Incidentally, I'm thinking this idea/technique could probably be leveraged to solve this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause) question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one will work with empty strings

```
DECLARE @InputString VARCHAR(1000)
    SELECT @InputString = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,,1'

    SELECT SUBSTRING(',' + @InputString + ',', Number + 1,
    CHARINDEX(',', ',' + @InputString + ',', Number + 1) - Number -1)AS VALUE
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'p'
    AND Number <= LEN(',' + @InputString + ',') - 1
    AND SUBSTRING(',' + @InputString + ',', Number, 1) = ','
    GO
```

Also take a look at the comments here: S[plit string in SQL Server 2005+ CLR vs. T-SQL](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/split-string-in-sql-server-2005-clr-vs-t) for some other ideas

Comment: Interesting as I guess that solution is basically forward recursion? Is there a more general solution that doesn't require master..spt_values (i.e. supports > 2047 items) ?

Comment: Something with ROW_NUMBER() maybe?

Comment: You can have your own number table, the reason I show spt_values is because every SQL Server installation has it

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose Row_Number() over say 2 x sysobjects joined would give me as many numbers as I needed.  I don't see any major difference in performance between this solution & mine (now ammended to terminate correctly), so still interested my question as to what the pitfalls of recursion here are?

Answer (score 2):

Though it's too late now and also the OP has an accepted answer, but still it's worth mentioning to read the article on [Split Function in Sql Server using Set base approach](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1797-split-function-in-sql-server-using-set-base-approach.aspx) where the author has shown many ways of achieving the same.